# dash all over my unity in asus k45vd

Tags: unity, asus

I installed ubuntu 13.10 in asus k45vd laptop. sometimes when I'm working with my laptop I see dashes all over my screen(showing them takes maybe less than one secconds so it's difficult to take screenshot.) This problem just is in unity in other desktops which I installed like xfce4, kde, gnome-shell there isn't this problem.

in ubuntu 13.04 there was this problem in my laptop too, and I tested ubuntu in another laptop asus k55vd there is this problem in that laptop too.
I thought this a unity bug in asus kxxvd series!

is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

u remove it by resetting your unity
You can do this by the following command

```
$ unity --reset
```

Comment: there is this problem after installation ubuntu. I thought reseting unity doesn't solve this problem.